# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'image' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `badge

Tags: laravel

The name of my controller is "BadgeController".This is my store function in BadgeController.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('image'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'image' => $new_name,
    );

    Badge::create($form_data);

    return redirect('badges.index')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
}
```

my table name is "badges". This is my table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('badges', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('images')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

the name of model is Badge. This is my model

```
class Badge extends Model
{
     use HasFactory;

     protected $table = 'badges';

     protected $fillable = [
        'image',
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to insert data in the "image" field, not in "images" field. That's why you get the error *Unkown column "image"*

```
 $image = $request->file('image');
```

correct it, also in your *$fillable* variable

Answer (score 0):

**copy this one:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request->validate([
         'image' => 'required',
    ]);
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $new_name = rand().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('image'), $new_name);
    $form_data = array(
        'images' => $new_name,
    );

    Badge::create($form_data);

    return redirect('badges.index')->with('success', 'Data Added successfully.');
}
```

**and change this:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'image',
 ];
```

**to:**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'images',
 ];
```